# Can I plant tagetes tenuifolia between grapevines and ribes?

Tags: flowers, vines

I am thinking of planting [tagetes tenuifolia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagetes_tenuifolia) to partly cover the ground between grapevines and ribes. Those stand in relatively large (approx. 10 x 0.75 m and 3 x 2 m respectively) and otherwise bare beds. I'd like to add some more color to the mix, if possible.

Is is this an advisable idea, and what other (pretty) plants could serve for the same purpose? (This is for a location in Central Europe. The grapes will be consumed, but their quantity is of no great concern. There are already some roses in between the vines.)

Comment: It could potentially make it harder to weed, and obstruct access. But having green cover on the ground is always best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with it.

What kind of ribes? I used to grow a few different gooseberries and currents in the Midwest of the USA.

Comment: Tx. Its redcurrants and gooseberry (if those are the right terms in English).

Comment: I grew pixwell gooseberries (thornless fruit), as well as some native and wild Marsh Gooseberries. I also had black currants, and I mean the ribes black currant, not the dried grape kind.